# Django Queryset for no-operation

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to specify a Django Queryset, which will do nothing but still be valid Queryset? Empty queryset should ideally not call DB and results would be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Model.objects.none()
```

always gives you an empty queryset

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MyModel.objects.none()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.none) which will return an `EmptyQuerySet`, which is a `QuerySet` subclass that always evaluates to an empty list.

For eg., if you have a model class `Entry` (or just use `models.Model`), you can simply create an `EmptyQuerySet` by:

```
>>> Entry.objects.none()
[]
```